# How to list all files where the first line is a blank line

Tags: command-line, bash, xargs

I would like to find all the Java files that have a blank line as the first line of the file.  I have the following which simply outputs the first line (and filename) of each file into the output file "fileList.txt":

```
find . -name *java | xargs head -n1 > fileList.txt
```

However I then need to post-process "fileList.txt" to find the empty filenames.

How can I add an "if" condition to the xargs so that it only outputs the filename if the first line is blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `| xargs`, find has an `-exec` flag to execute a command on matching files. Also, you need to escape the `*java` or bash will expand the arguments and `find` will complain.

This `awk` oneliner then should do what you need:

```
find . -name '*java' -exec awk 'NR==1&&/^$/{print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

`NR==1` selects just the first line. `/^$/` matches the empty line. `print FILENAME` prints the file that matches.

If the first line is not *really empty* but contains only whitespace, you can modify the regular expression in

```
/^\s*$/
```

where `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Note that this (1) invokes awk once for each file found and (2) awk reads the whole of each file - if you have GNU awk you could make it more efficient by passing multiple files and moving to the next as soon as you've tested the first line e.g. `-exec gawk '/^$/ {print FILENAME} {nextfile}' {} +`

Comment: @MrShunz great answer. You were right about that the lines were not really empty and so the regular expression part was very useful.

Comment: FYI `\s` probably only works in GNU awk - if you have `mawk` for example (which was the default awk on some previous versions of Ubuntu) you will likely need to use something like `/^[ \t]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate using `sed`:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -n '/^$/F;q' {} \;
```

Note that it will be somewhat inefficient for large numbers of small files since it invokes `sed` once for each file - however it only reads one line of each.

To handle lines that are empty except for whitespace, change `/^$/` to `/^[[:blank:]]*$/` or `/^[ \t]*$/` (space-tab).